# Repeated CASE Statement: Is there a more efficient way of writing this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an Excel formula I need to reproduce in MySQL of the format:
MAX(IF(A= "", B-C, B-D), 0)
Basically if the inner IF is < 0 return zero.

I have written this as:

```
IF ( CASE
       WHEN  A IS NULL
       THEN B-C
       ELSE B-D
     END > 0,
     CASE
       WHEN  A IS NULL
       THEN B-C
       ELSE B-D
     END, 0 )
```

But I can't help think there is a simpler way of writing this, after all I'm executing the CASE statement twice here. I'm rusty with mySQL and until I'm up to scratch was wondering what the most code efficient way of writing this would be

Comment: Your `case` expression has `B-C` which your Excel expression does not.  Your `case` expression handles `NULL` values; your Excel expression does not.

Comment: Oops. My bad, the excel statement should be B-C  and I'm effectively having to replace the 0's with Nulls in the  database variant. I'll update the Excel code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically if the inner IF is < 0 return zero.

Going by this, you can simply do:

```
select greatest(b - d, 0)
```

I am not quite sure what your code -- in Excel or SQL -- has to do with this statement, though.

Comment: so basically: GREATEST ( CASE statement., 0 ) makes sense but it doesn't seem to work when I run it. I'll look into it though, thanks, much more efficient method:

Comment: Actually it was an error in my syntax,  and it works fine. Thanks.